# Вылетает context при повторном обращение к таймеру на Android

Tags: java, android

Собственно сам код, находится в отдельном класса, запускается из MainActivity

```
    public Timer(long millisInFuture, final long countDownInterval, final ITimerCallback callback, final Context context) {

        currentTimer = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long time = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                callback.ontTimerNewValue(String.valueOf(time));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                callback.ontTimerNewValue("ОК");


                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Запускаю из MainActivity следующим образом:

```
        new Timer(timer_ot_do, 1000, new Timer.ITimerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void ontTimerNewValue(String value) {
                timer_vivod.setText(value);
            }
        } , MainActivity.this);
    }
```

Всё работает прекрасно но при повторном запуске таймера из той же функции, на builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); бьёт ошибку:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
```

То есть context со второго раза по какой то причине не передаётся. В чём может быть загвозка?

Comment: У меня есть догадки что это связано с final Context context ... он как бы передаёт его единожды

Answer (score 0):

```
 var timer = object : CountDownTimer(TIMER_WAITING, TIMER_INTERVAL) {
    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

    }

    override fun onFinish() {
        )
    }
}
```

где TIMER_WAITING - время с которого будет идти отсчет , TIMER_INTERVAL- интервал с которым этот отсчет будет идти 
у меня такая реализация работает

Comment: Это вообще что? У меня Context не передаётся. В этом проблема